# Is it possible to alter the form in element_validate?

Tags: 7, forms

I have an `#element_validate` function and I'd like it to be able to alter the form values that are sent back to the user in the case of other validation errors.

i.e.

1. User submits form with field1 invalid, field2 valid.
2. field2 has my `#element_validate` function on it. It's valid and I now want to set the value of it to something else, say `foo`.
3. User gets form again with message about field1 being invalid, and hopefully with field2 set to `foo`.

I've tried this in my element validate callback:

```
form_set_value($element, 'foo', $form_state);
$form_state['complete form'][$element['#name']]['#value'] = 'foo';
```

But it seems neither of these result in foo coming through in the form.

Comment: I ran into this problem recently - it doesn't seem possible: https://www.drupal.org/node/1898856 I wasn't able to get it working myself.

Comment: Actually, I think it *is* working. Thanks to that 2nd line of code in my example (without that it definitely isn't working). I'm going to delete this question.